# Failed to deserialize json string to target

Tags: java, json, rest

I am using Postman to run the below Rest API code. After running this code, I am getting error message:     ***"technical": "Failed to deserialize json string to target type com.silanis.esl.api.model.Field", "message": "Invalid JSON***. I am not sure how to resolve this error message. I am trying to add a field to a package. How can I correct this code so that it will add a field in the package and run correctly? I am new to using Rest API, so could use some suggestions on getting this to work.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
'https://sandbox.esignlive.com/api/packages/WlnHZN0WH1xKX6GHGTFbQtGPBJg=/documents/cec7f9fa480589d46a91944ca2b4e8921df2aaef094ae042/approvals/MfSNKUFMhHIB/fields' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic api_key' \
  -H  { "id": "date_field", "name": "date_field", "type": "INPUT",  "subtype": "LABEL", "value": "2023-01-01", "page": 0, "width": 269.9928097345133, "height": 59.986172566371685,  "top": 694.5371497050148, "left": 275.8079830383481 }
```

Comment: The most obvious part is that there are no quotes around your json though there are around your other parameters. Try to add them. Also, the json is not a header. It's the query data.

Comment: Thank you. Tried that, now I am getting: Error: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["{ "id""]

Comment: As I said, the data is not a header, so why are you putting it after `-H`?